# Multiple Popup Boxes with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, popupwindow

I have this code where you have multiple elements and, when you click a link on each element, it opens a different popup window. I figured out how to do this by making different divs for each element. But I plan to have at least 50+ elements that all need different windows. I was wondering if there was a way to still have different windows popup with just one div? Maybe with a javascript function?

Here are examples of one element.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickam,.fadeam').click(function() {
        $('#popam').fadeToggle();
    });
});
</script>

#popam {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;left:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    background:rgba(15,17,6,.9);
    display:none;
}

.fadeam {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.clickam {
    position:relative; 
}
```

Here is a link to the full code I use: [link](https://pastebin.com/b4CUPfN4).

[This](https://codesbysugar.tumblr.com/code/31) is a representation of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript rather than Java (they are different languages)? If just one div how do you want the user to indicate which function they want?

Comment: Yes, I meant Javascript. Sorry, I'm still learning. And I was hoping that I could create one div to design the look of the window, then possibly use javascript to extract information from each element to differentiate.

Comment: _"Here is a link to the full code I use"_ - a proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly inside your question, please do not send us to external platforms.